# Kentico 7 - Display an image from media library in web part

Tags: c#, image, media, kentico

I have created a custom web part for Kentico that needs to allow the content manager to select an image from the media library that will be set as a background image in a div. The form control I am using is Media Selection. Does anyone know how I can write the aspx and c# code to display the selected image? I feel like this should be an easy answer but I am coming up short. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileAbsoluteUrl()` or `MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileUrl()` to get absolute or relative URL of the desired image and use it in aspx markup or codebehind. If you want to get "nice" URL, use example described [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums/f47/fp8/t19577/Media-Library-API-Class.aspx).